# Closed Domain Question Answering which doesn't answer Questions

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, question-answering

I've been exploring Closed Domain Question Answering Implementations which have been trained on SQuAD 2.0 dataset. Ideally, it should not answer questions which the context text corpus doesn't contain answers to. But while implementing such models using the `Haystack` repo or the `FARM` repo, I'm finding that it always answers these questions even when it shouldn't. Is there any implementation available that takes into account the fact that it shouldn't answer questions when it doesn't find a suitable answer.

References:

1. https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/update-tutorials/tutorials/Tutorial3_Basic_QA_Pipeline_without_Elasticsearch.ipynb#scrollTo=KS4nTwxIbRb6
2. https://github.com/deepset-ai/FARM
3. https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack
4. https://huggingface.co/deepset/bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-squad2
5. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UrKlHlf68hD3wwQDTctx2cQs6FMUxLLH?usp=sharing#scrollTo=J4jxYsxaG77O

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @IlkerKurtulus yes I did, I also found a scalable implementation of the same from `Haystack` library. Thank You!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Question Answering model of `simpletransformers` takes data with `is_impossible` option in the training phase. Also during prediciton, it does not generate answers for all questions since the model learns which questions should be answered.

You can find details below:

https://pypi.org/project/simpletransformers/